# Invalid Hook Call Error when using react useState hook inside firebase app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am trying to get react hooks to work.  Here is the function component:

```
function useHooksExample() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);
  setFoo(5);
  return foo;
}
```

I call this via:

```
useHooksExample();
```

I get an error as follows:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
>   of a function component. This could happen for one of the following
>   reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.

I've debugged and confirmed I am using a single react version. Perhaps I am using state hooks incorrectly?

---

Here is where I am calling the custom hook from:

```
    class TableData extends Component {
       componentDidMount() {
        useHooksExample();
   }
}
    export default TableData;
```

Comment: can you add the code of component where you are using your custom hook?

Comment: Added the code above...

Comment: Hooks cannot be called from inside class components. They are only usable inside functional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are only for use inside function components. You can convert `TableData` into a function component in order to use your hook:

```js
export default function TableData() {
  const foo = useHooksExample();
  return <div />;
}
```

This is covered in the "[Only Call Hooks from React Functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)" section of the Rules of Hooks.

Comment: Thanks Ross - I missed the fact they have to not only be outside a class, but called from outside one as well.  Thanks.